# Error Code -1073741515 When Using EDITBIN

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using EditBin to increase the stack size of an application I'm writing. I have this in the post-build event command line for Visual Studio:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /STACK:268435456 "$(TargetPath)"
```

When I build my project, I get this error:

> Error 470 The command ""C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 10.0\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /STACK:268435456 "[Target Executable]"" exited
> with code -1073741515.

I have both of the following in my PATH environment variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin

The command also works when I run it manually with cmd.exe. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: -1073741515 is c0000135 in hex. Error c0000135 is "Unable To Locate Component" which is the error you are getting.

Comment: As a note: the value signed decimal integer value `-1073741515` is interpreted as an unsigned integer in order to convert it to the hexadecimal integer value `c0000135`, as noted at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22038660/1959808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work for now by copying mspdb100.dll into the same directory as editbin.exe, but this is not an optimal solution because every developer on my team will need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, how I resolved it:

Ran `msbuild.exe <my.sln> /t:<mytargetproject>` from a VS2010 command prompt, where `<my.sln>` is your solution name and `<mytargetproject>` is the project you are trying to build. For e.g. `msbuild.exe helloworld.sln /t:mainproj`.

When you do this or at least when I ran this, a dialog box popped up and said "foo.dll" cannot be found, I added the path of that dll to my "PATH" environment variable and the problem was solved! See ChrisF's comment to the question, as it says, the error is that some dll/component is missing.

From the dll name it complained about, I believe this is not contained to VS2010 libs/dlls, for me it was a third-party dll (which I am using and supposed to be available during the build) it was complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to run the vcvarsall.bat located in the root of the visual studio install folder(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC). That sets up the search folders for all MSVC compiler related tools.