# "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I downloaded the express version of VC++ and the Windows SDK. I need to compile my code in a 64-bit compiler. When compiling, I get the following error:

> "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515

What does this error mean?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808

Answer (score 6):

The value -1073741515 is 0xC0000135 in hex, which basically means "some dll not found". (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57083-1073741515-problem)

Comment: Specifically, `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Searched for this solution a full day until I came accross this answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful & generic guide to convert these *cl.exe* exit codes to human meaningful messages here:
[Visual Studio 2010 C native compilation problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18dc2101-ea44-44e8-af2c-c6bf4869582e/visual-studio-2010-c-native-compilation-problem?forum=msbuild)

To summarize:

- convert the negative decimal exit code to a hexadecimal number (you can use the Windows built in calculator in the Programmer mode for this)
- take the last 8 hexadecimal digits and search them in the table on the [Microsoft NT status codes web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One way I produced this return code with the full version of Visual Studio is to run the vcvarsall.bat script once for 32-bit and later for 64-bit. In this case, start a fresh command prompt instead.

The question here specifically refers to the Express edition. Express only supports compiling 32-bit executables, even on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This error code is mostly due to missing dlls that are required by your program. There can be two solutions.

1. Locate the primary dlls that are required by your program. In my case specifically, I pasted SDL.dll in the binary directory.
2. After step 1, I still got the error saying packet.dll not found. So I installed WinPcap the main source of packet.dll

This is the procedure that I followed to resolve this error. Thanks