# git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1073741515)

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, git-gui

I have `TortoiseGit` and `MySysGit` installed on `Windows 8 64 bit`. It was working fine 2 days back but stopped working suddenly. It works fine on `Git Bash`.

Here is the detailed error message:

`git.exe pull -v --progress      "" develop`

`git did not exit cleanly (exit code -1073741515)`

I have checked the path for `Mysysgit.exe` which points to right directory.

Any help would be great?

Comment: Using SSH? Go to TortoiseGit's issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/list for more help.

Comment: @linquize `SSH` is working fine but i am not able `git pull` or `git push` using `GUI`

Comment: What version of msysgit are you using?

Comment: Do you use putty or OpenSSH?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808