# Can't build c++ projects in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just installed visual studio 2017 on windows 7 and every time I try to build a c++ project I get this error:

```
Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

No mather what is the content of c++ file, every time this error occurs, even hello world fails to build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038660/visual-studio-2013-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515

Comment: @AlanBirtles So installation of v140 toolset should solve the problem?

Comment: probably not, uninstalling and reinstalling is probably the best option, otherwise contact microsoft for support