# Qt OpenCV programm exits with code -1073741515

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

### What i want to do

I try to use opencv and run a short example program.

### Problem

It exits with code `-1073741515`. I never managed to use openCV on any of the 4 systems i tried, so i do something wrong but don't know what.

I had diffrenet errors using different attempts (undefined reference, crashing programm without error code, etc.), this here is the just simplest example.

### What i figured out

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038660/visual-studio-2013-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515) told me, that `-1073741515` is equal to `0xC0000135` meaning `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

### What i tried

The programm crashes, if include `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`, 
`#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>`and 
`#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`. When i comment them out, it runs wnd returns 0 as intended. I don't even need to use anything like `cv::Mat` or something to make it crash. That seems strange, because the code completion suggests me stuff from openCV, so it somehow sees it. Including `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` instead leads to the same error code. Including something beginning with opencv (not opencv2) works, for example `#include <opencv/cv.hpp>`, but has not enough functionality.

### Source file

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat InputImage = cv::imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg");

    if(!InputImage.empty())
        cv::imshow("test", InputImage);
    else
        cout << "imgage is empty" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Project file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += D:/opencv/build/include
LIBS += -LD:/opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_world343d
LIBS += -lopencv_world343

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

### Relevant folders

Include path:

[image: include path]

libs:

[image: libs]

project:

[image: project]

build (copied the libs to the release/debug folders too):

[image: build]

### Versions

- QT 5.10.1
- MSVC17 64bit Compiler
- Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit
- openCV 3.4.3 (vc14/vc15)

Comment: Where is opencv_world343.dll? If it's not static build, need put the dlls in `build-xxx-debug` folder

Comment: LIBS += -LD:/opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib shoud be "vc15", link to xxxd.lib only in debug and to xxx.lib only in release, and need to put .dll into the same folder as the exe

Comment: Thanks Jiu :-) it works, if i copy the .dll instead of .lib.
Thanks Miki: I tried both vc14 and vc15, that didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the hint where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308570/jiu) pointed out in the comment above, the solution was simple:

Copy the `.dll` not the `.lib` and it works.