# Reading an image exits with error code -1073741515 ("Some dll not found")

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, dll

I have a very simple program to test my opencv installation:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
int main() {
        // read an image
        cv::Mat image= cv::imread("c:\\img.jpg");
        // create image window named "My Image"
        cv::namedWindow("My Image");
        // show the image on window
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        cv::waitKey(0);
        return 1;
}
```

I am using Qt Creator for this and when I run the code it exits with the error: -1073741515, which according to this post:http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57083-1073741515-problem relates to a dll not found.

This is really annoying as I am sure I have pretty much done everything according to the book. Here is my pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-03-30T06:33:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = opencv_pls
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += D:\\opencv_bin\\install\\include
LIBS += -LD:\\opencv_bin\\lib \
    -lopencv_core2410.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui2410.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc2410.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d2410.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d2410.dll
```

And here is my `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;D:\Qt\4.7.0\bin;D:\mingw\bin;D:\OpenCV-2.2.0_bin\bin;D:\OpenCV-2.2.0_bin\include;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;d:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\runtime\win64;d:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v81\runtime\win32;
```

Everything seems to be in order.

Dependency Walker shows these errors:

[image]

But according to this post: [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) these are all false positives.

WHAT am I missing??? I'm nearly at the stage of pulling my hair out. 
Help please

Comment: just a suggestion(I dont know if it will solve the issue) 
For "core" and "highgui" your are using opencv2 but for "cv.h" you are using "opencv"

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the issue, I tried with both 2 and 1, also commenting the line out, still get the same error

Comment: sorry to comment without proper solution but when you say "LIBS +=" it should be ".lib" file not ".dll" file?

Comment: Thats alright, at least someone is reading my question. Those files are lib files I think. As every opencv guide directs it. Like this one: http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml and many like it

Comment: Faraz make sure that you dlls and libs are present in current folder,I have this kind of issues in c++.Just checking all the possibilities.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808