# Program returns with error code -1073741515 in CodeBlocks for Windows on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks, mingw32

I am currently trying to write an OpenCV test application on CodeBlocks for Windows using the mingw32 compiler. I built the OpenCV sources using CMake and mingw32 successfully with no errors. All libraries were added and the PATH environment variable set.
The following is the code I've used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Program start\n";
    getch();
    cv::Mat frame;
    return 0;
}
```

The file builds with no errors. However on execution I get the following message:

'Process return -1073741515 <0xC0000135>'

Even the first "Program start" is not printed on screen

I did refer to this article: [Error Code -1073741515 When Using EDITBIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189109/error-code-1073741515-when-using-editbin) but that was futile.

Comment: What conio.h doing here? Comment from answer you're provided clearly state about your error - " -1073741515 is c0000135 in hex. Error c0000135 is "Unable To Locate Component" ", which means that one of required DLL not found.

Comment: Can you compile a basic [Hello World](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/120679/) program?

Comment: Conio. h was used for getch as a makeshift to pause execution before the statement using CV namespace. Any attempt to use something related to OpenCV, be it a data type or a function call results in this error. The required DLLs are present on disc and have been linked properly. Compiling a hello world program or other simple programs without OpenCV usage succeeds with no error.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808