# Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) after trying to run sample code using OpenCV library

Tags: windows, opencv, clion

I've been trying to run **OpenCV** using **CLion IDE** under **Windows**. When I try to run this sample code for loading and displaying an image

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread("earth.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error statement:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

As for the content in my **CMakeLists.txt**, it looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Where to find CMake modules and OpenCV
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:\\opencv\\mingw-build\\install")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(openCV main.cpp)

# add libs you need
set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)

# linking
target_link_libraries(openCV ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: When you run it in a debugger, what line of code triggers the exception?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The code didn't even run, then I figured out an issue with _OpenCV binary path in system variables_. It solved my problem.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add OpenCV binary path with DLLs to your PATH BEFORE CLion start.
I do it from script:

```
=== CLionWithMingwAndOpenCV.bat ==========================
@echo off
set PATH=C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin;D:\opencv\release\bin;%PATH%

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion XXXX\bin\clion64.exe"
=== ==========================
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already added the binary path to system variables prior to your answer. Upon your suggestion, I had checked it once again and found out that I missspelled the path. Instead of x64 folder I put x86. Thanks anyway, now it seems to work :)