# error MSB6006: "midl.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem during C++ project build in VS2015 update 3. the error message is as follow:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1318,5): error MSB6006: "midl.exe" exited with code -1073741515
```

Edit:
This is a project which using SDK 10.0.150310.
On Windows 10 the build succeeded but on Windows 7 failed with the error as described.

Comment: have you found which DLL is missing?

Comment: using missins DLL or installing win8 SDK didn't helped.
only compiling it on windows10 or windows server2016 solved the issue (stopped fighting with it because originally the code wrote on win10..)

Comment: ok, post this answer

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using missins DLL or installing win8 SDK didn't helped. only compiling it on windows10 or windows server2016 solved the issue (stopped fighting with it because originally the code wrote on win10..)

Answer (score 0):

The error `-1073741515 == 0xC0000135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`:

```
STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND                                           ntstatus.h

The program can't start because %hs is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

So a dll is missing. Use [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), capture the activity and filter for DLL loading events. Now look in Result column where you see an error. Now look which DLL is missing.

Comment: I see the first DLL in system32 folder (Windows 8), but I also miss the second. Looks like VS2015 needs those DLL which Win7 doesn't have. If you want to debug your app for Win7, compile it on WIn10 and use Remote Debugging Tools to debug the Application on Windows 7

Comment: Did found two missing DLL files in the Result column says NAME NOT FOUND: api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1.dll and api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll. those are related to win8.1 sdks so i downloaded and installed it. but the error still exist.

Comment: now that i have the dll files (took it from win8 OS), installation with gacutil return "Failure adding assembly to the cache:   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.", and those are files which located unfer multiple locations as i checked in win8.

Comment: what do you want to do now with GACUtil?

Comment: again, what do you want to do with GACutil?