# Visual studio - how to check what DLLs does my program need to run/what DLLs are missed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cl

I've just downloaded the Visual Studio 2017 Community.
Once I try to compile any program (even the simplest "Hello World") with any configuration (release/debug, x86/x64, empty project/windows console application), I get the following error:

`Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(381,5): error MSB6006: error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515` (This error means `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`, I know it's been asked before, but I don't know how to check what DLLs are missed).

```
Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(381):
   <CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and
   '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and
   '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"
```

Do you know how to check what DLLs are missing?

Comment: That is not what it really means, it actually means "install failed, abandon hope".  You can't assume it is was just one file that disappeared.  Running chkdsk.exe is important.  Rerunning the installer to repair/reinstall is next.

Comment: @Hans Passant I've run chkdsk.exe before, because I've found similiar answer somewhere else (nothing was wrong). Anyway, already got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new but i hope I'll answer quite properly. To reach the actual error code you need to change it to hex. Yours is

> C0000135

. As far as I know it's file damage related,so you're right about dll missing. In older visuals the way to know it was via command line.

> Ran `msbuild.exe <my.sln> /t:<mytargetproject>` from a VS2010 command prompt, where `<my.sln>` is your solution name and `<mytargetproject>` is the project you are trying to build. For e.g. `msbuild.exe helloworld.sln /t:mainproj`.

That is a cite from different post in stackoverflow.

> [Error Code -1073741515 When Using EDITBIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189109/error-code-1073741515-when-using-editbin)

Hope it will be easier for you to resolve problem with this. Can't help more as I don't use VS neither Windows. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed 2 DLLs. After downloading them, everything compiles properly.