# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

**Android Studio 4.0, Emulator 30.0.12, Win 10**

Everything has been ok, but today my AVD emulator stopped start and started to show error like this:

`The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed.`

if I start it from the *AVD Manager* or if I started Debug my project then:

`Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)`

**I tried:**

1. remove and install Android Studio ;
2. reinstalled all plugins, gradle, sdk, emulator;

But it all doesn't effect to it.

May be anyone knows how fix this bug?
Thx!

Comment: Please run the emulator from cmd (on Windows) with `$ANDROID_SDK/emulator/emulator -avd <NameOfAVD> -verbose -show-kernel` and add more logs and info to the question. I've also faced the same situation with the v 30 emulator which has "**Failed to create Vulkan instance**". This might be the same error you get?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท thank U so much, I've tried it and get this: 
"vcruntime140_1.dll was not found." 
I've installed it from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads and everything is ok again!

Comment: Good to hear that, should I add an answer? I'm sure Android Studio's log doesn't really show the whole errors and this can help others too!

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท sure, do it!)

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4189109/1959808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also faced the same situation many times and didn't get *the exact* error of why this happening from Android Studio.

To understand of what causes this issue, try running the emulator from command line (*cmd on Windows*) which will also show the whole errors and issues you have:

```
$ANDROID_SDK/emulator/emulator -avd <NameOfAVD> -verbose -show-kernel
```

---

P.S: To get the list of avd devices, go to `"sdk_path\emulator"` then run:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: .\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_33 -verbose -show-kernel
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\ 
is all I get when I try

Comment: Please check if you have Windows Media Pack installed, this is required to run emulator, it's not documented and not may users notice, I have Windows 11 Enterprise N which is the N variant that does come without Media Pack and emulator didn't work until I installed it.

Apps > Optional Features > Add feature > Windows Media Pack