# I am not able to start my AVD or Emulator in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

While running Emulator its shows Emulator was Killed.

In Activity Log I can see an error named as:
"Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)"

**I have tried---->**

1. To clean/wipe and cold reset
2. Even I have tried by creating a new Emulator with RAM size 4 Gb also. But still, I faced the same problem which I had encountered earlier.
3. My IDE and SDK are updated.
4. I had also tried to configure my AVD's Graphics from Automatic to Software-GLS 2.0 but that doesn't work too.
5. But the same project can be run on my Android Phone.
6. My PC's Virtualisation is "Enabled"

**Please Help me with that...**

Answer (score 0):

There's some suggestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721513/emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135) about running the emulator from the command line, so you get some more useful info.

Since you mentioned RAM size, make sure you have enough local storage on the virtual device too - I've had a lot of problems where I've tried to keep it low (it'll be fine! I'm only installing one small app!) and the emulator misbehaves and won't run properly